# Combine 2 answers to if statements on the same line

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Hi I'm new to python and I'm trying to combine the answers to two different if statements onto the same line. How can I make them appear on the same line.

```
if ar == "Y":
print("coating(s):\nanti reflective")
if pf == "Y":
print("polarized filters")
```

How can I get the two printed statements to appear on the same line when its run. I just don't know what to use to do this so i haven't tried much.

Comment: Please try to fix the indentation of your code, as what you have provided is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the new line at the end of the first print statement, use

```
print("coating(s):\nanti reflective", end="")
```

Please read the [documentation of the print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)